# I want to write json files with data that I scraped with a webscraper and an Api of a website however I get a TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, encoding, pycharm, pickle

I have built a webscraper that collects and manipulates a bunch of data. Then I also have an Api that gives me other pieces of data on the website that I have scraped. Now I wish to combine both sets of data into a json file that I am trying to write. However once my program tries to grab pieces of data from my webscraper it seems to run into a 'TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable'

ive tried integrating some custom encoders presented in other problem here to no avail.

some of the custom encoders I have tried:

```
class PythonObjectEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (list, dict, str, unicode, int, float, bool, type(None))):
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        return {'_python_object': pickle.dumps(obj)}

def as_python_object(dct):
    if '_python_object' in dct:
        return pickle.loads(str(dct['_python_object']))
    return dct
```

## main script:

```
with open('C:/Users/Maximvs/PycharmProjects/Scrapy/planInfo/planInfo/spiders/Freedom_api.json') as json_file:
    dataRaw = json.load(json_file)
    dataText = dataRaw
    # data = json.loads(dataText)
    # print(type(dataRaw))


def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = '' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'

    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)


path = 'C:/Users/Maximvs/Documents/Scraper_Plans'


for Linkindex,link in enumerate(PhonePermutationLinks): #goes through all phone models and plans permutations
    fileName = str(phonesListExtended[Linkindex]) + " " + str(phonePlansListExtended[Linkindex])
```

error received:

File "C:\Users\Maximvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)

File "C:\Users\Maximvs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '

TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

im hoping to use the lists I have built with the data from the webscraper(which I iterate through) and dictionaries from an Api to create a json file that contains pieces of data from each.

Comment: `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

From this error message, it seems you have a  Python "set" in your object, which python does not serialize to JSON by default. To your encoder, add another condition to handle `isinstance(obj, set)` and coerce set to a list, which can be done easily, by `list(set_value)`

Comment: how would that look in my encoder?

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (list, dict, str, unicode, int, float, bool, type(None))):
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, set):
            list(set_value)

Comment: You could try: `elif isinstance(obj, set): return JSONEncoder.default(list(obj))`